# Implicit Coercion of value type of flash.display.SimpleButton

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax, syntax-error

My code is this:

```
symboll.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, symboll);
function ball_hit_wall(e:Event):void{
        (symboll.hitTestObject(box));
{   
        gotoAndPlay(3)
    }
}
```

And the error message that i am getting is this:

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:SimpleButton to an unrelated type Function.

I'm new to actionscript, what did i do wrong

symboll and box are both buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `addEventListener` expects second argument of the type `Function`, while you're providing type `SimpleButton`.

Try replace your code

```
symboll.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, symboll);
```

with

```
symboll.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball_hit_wall);
```